# Resonant circuit using LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, resonance, bode-plot

I'm a college student and I was supposed to draw the Bode-plot of the following resonant circuit.

[image: my resonant circuit]

I obtained this.

[image]

My questions are: shouldn't I have obtained a bell-shaped curve? How can I find the resonance frequency using the plot itself?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You appear to have -30dB of baseline gain... so... I think you did something wrong.

Comment: RL looks absurdly large, it will eliminate any resonance. On the other hand, at LF the input network reduces to a 100k/1.6k pad, for -36dB gain. In conjunction with a *2 amplifier, -30dB overall looks about right. (Also, why both positive AND negative feedback?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I think you meant to say "... both negative AND positive feedback?" The positive feedback is the unusual component in this deign. Beware.

Comment: For other people to try this out for themselves it would be useful to provide the .asc file. Then we could also see if for U1 you really use +15V for both supplies...